# Android gallery item jerks when it comes to focus

Tags: android

I am inflating a listview in one of the item in gallery. When I scroll through gallery and when my list view is in focus I observe a slight jerk in the gallery.

How to avoid the jerk?

Please let me know the solution if any.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How do you load your images?

If you read them from the sd card as part of getView in the Adapter, this will cause a file IO operation that blocks the UI thread for up to 500 ms.

Load the file through an async task, and while it is loading use a default loading drawable from your app.